# exchange 2000 route one address to external server

Tags: email, exchange, routing

In Exchange 2000 in an AD, configured with a default e-maildomain domainname.com and multiple users and mailboxes on the server, is it possible to route 1 internal mailaddress to an external server?

For example: When **user1@domainname.com** sends an e-mail to **user2@domainname.com**, the mail doesn't leave the server. But when an e-mail is send to **user3@domainname.com**, the mail should be send via an external smtp-server.

Thanks in advance for your reactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your internal domain is domainname.com then mail to user3@domainname.com will always be processed internally. The best you can do is configure user3's mailbox to forward to user3@someotherdomain.com.

If this is OK then fire up your AD Users and Computers and create a Contact, and set the SMTP address to user3@someotherdomain.com. Now open the properties for user3, go to the Ecxhange General tab and click the Delivery button. Select your newly created Contact as the forwarding address.

This is what is described in support.microsoft.com/kb/281926. You're correct when you say "forwarding only seems to work when forwarding to objects within the Active Directory" but the contact you've created is an Active Directory object but any mail sent to it goes to it's external e-mail address.

JR

Comment: Thanks, creating a Contact in AD with the e-mailadres @someotherdomain.com was indeed the perfect solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use a **Forwarding Address**. I don't have access to an Exchange 2000 box to verify where it is in the UI, but in 2007 it's in *Mail Flow > Delivery Options > Forwarding Address*.

Comment: Thanks. I found the following explanation from Microsoft on forwarding: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281926

Unfortunately, forwarding only seems to work when forwarding to objects within the Active Directory, not to outside e-mailaddresses.

Comment: You can create a contact object in the Active Directory that refers to an external email address. That's the way to do what you're trying to do. renniej hit the nail on the head with his answer.